# AAPT2 Unexpected error while building signed for release (works for debug)

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt2

I have been looking for any solution since last few days. I havn't been releasing new version for some time, so hard to say when it started. I have try t reverso code, tried different versions of AS and Graddle and still nothing.

During building signed bundle or apk with the Release build definition I got this error:

```
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-beta01-5013011-windows Daemon #1: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\xxxx\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\xyz_background.png', attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Any idea where to look for any solution?

Comment: check your layouts (.xml files) for issues like missing closure, or character

Comment: check usages of problematic file

Comment: You are using the AS 3.4 beta?

Comment: @IrwinNawrocki just checked all layout files (found only one additional closure. File is only used in 6 of those.

Comment: @AhmedHegazy Checked on 3.2, 3.3 and 3.4bata

Comment: The last line tells you what to do; file an issue in the Google issue tracker

Comment: @Zoe Will do, tx :) I have checked my code on a different PC and works fine, so probably issue is generated by me system. Thank you all for your support

Comment: `xxxhdpi` and `background.png` clearly hint for the file being too large to be processed.